Showing the product in category and search with Magento 2 Observer
I have defined an attribute in Magento 2. When I say Dont Show in Category in this attribute, I do not want the product to be shown in Category and Search. But I don't want to completely remove the product's URL, this is important for me in terms of SEO. Can you help me?
I made the visible property and it did not show the product in the category or search, but when I entered the URL, it gave a 404 error.

You should override class \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility.
This class provides a backend for managing product visibility and allows you to define conditions for product display in catalogs, search results, and by direct URL.

Add VISIBILITY_IN_SITE to class \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility like this



Add VISIBILITY_IN_SITE to function getVisibleInSiteIds()


public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
{
  return [self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_SITE];
}



Add VISIBILITY_IN_SITE to function getOptionArray() like this ,
'Site' is labels to show this option on backend


 public static function getOptionArray()
 {
    return [
      self::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE => __('Not Visible Individually'),
      self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG => __('Catalog'),
      self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH => __('Search'),
      self::VISIBILITY_BOTH => __('Catalog, Search'),
      self::VISIBILITY_IN_SITE => __('Site'),
    ];
 }


In the backend, you'll gain a new "Visibility" option called "Site." Products assigned this visibility will be hidden from both category pages and search results. However, customers can still access the product detail page directly using the product URL.

this work for me
